# $A$ be a $10\times 10$ matrix in which each row has exactly one entry equal to 1. find the possible value of the determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

Let $A$ be a $10\times 10$ matrix in which each row has exactly one entry equal to $1$. And remaining nine entries of the row being $0$. Which of the following is not a possible value of the determinant?
$0, 1 ,-1, 10$.
I am able to identify for $2\times 2$ cross two matrices for which possible value of determinant is $1$ or $-1$. How to identify for such a big size matrix? Can we identify such matrix?

Comment: For $2 \times 2$ matrices, $1$ and $-1$ are not the only possibilities. What is the third possibility? Now try it for $3 \times 3$ matrices. What's the pattern?

Comment: Third possibility may be zero.But i am not sure about that.

Comment: The third possibility is indeed $0$. The [Leibniz formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_determinants) for the determinant easily implies that $1,-1$, and $0$ are the only possibilities, but you may not be familiar with it.

Comment: Unfortunately i am not familiar with it.

Comment: You can still prove the result by thinking about what happens when you row-reduce such a matrix, if you know how row-reduction affects the determinant. For that matter, you can see it if you think about the determinant in terms of cofactor expansions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding or subtracting a row of a matrix from another does not change its determinant, so we may assume each column of the matrix has at most one entry that is 1.

Swapping rows of a matrix changes the sign of the determinant only; so if we perform row swaps so that the resulting matrix is diagonal, we'll have determined the determinant up to a sign.

So now we have a diagonal matrix whose diagonal entries are either 1 or 0.
The determinant of this matrix must be $0$ or $1$; and hence, the determinant of the original matrix must be $0$, $1$, or $-1$.

(The $-1$ possibility can arise: start with the identity matrix and interchange the last two rows. The 0 possibility can arise: start with a matrix whose first column is all $1$'s. And, of course, the identity matrix shows that $1$ is a possible value of the determinant.)

Comment: The opening sentence is not clear, since subtracting a row from another may break the requirement that every row has _exactly_ on nonzero entry (which is equal to $1$), so you are not reducing to another instance of the same problem. On the other hand you may generalise the statement to require only that each row has _at most_ one nonzero entry, and then the above proof works. The only doubt remains is whether the possibilty of getting $0$ might be due _only_ to weaking the condition, but a simple example shows it is not.

Answer (score 1):

The possible values of Determinant will be {0,1,-1}. Let me explain how.
We can consider A to be either an identity matrix(All the diagonal elements are 1). Hence it will satisfy the condition for A(exactly one entry in each row equal to 1). The determinant value of the Identity matrix is 1.
Now in this identity matrix, if we interchange a row/column, the sign of the value of determinant changes. So it becomes -1.
Now, since there is no condition that a column also has to have a single 1 throughout the column, hence we can consider that there are two identical rows in A, such that the position of 1 is the same in both the rows. Since, if a determinant contains identical rows/columns, its value is 0, therefore 0 is also a possible value for A.